# Using Reflection to get object constructor parameters

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way to use Reflection to get the object constructor parameters from the below constructor? (The "APN", "AVD", ....)

**Here is my Constructor:**

```
public EPayAppParams() : base("EPayAppParams", "AP")
{
    moAppName = new EPayParamNode(this, "APN");
    moVirtualDir = new EPayParamNode(this, "AVD");
    moVirtualPhone = new EPayParamNode(this, "AVP");
    moCallCenterTransferPhone = new EPayParamNode(this, "ATP");
    moAppPassword = new EPayParamNode(this, "APW");
}
```

**What the Property definition looks like for each of the above:**

```
[Description("Application Name"), Category("General")]
public string ApplicationName
{
    get { return moAppName.Value; }
    set { moAppName.Value = value; }
}
```

I want to relate the "moAppName" to "APN" so I could build a table of all the variables and their abbreviations.

Comment: Could you describe a little bit more what you want to do. You want to call the ctor from another project?

Comment: I've edited my question above, does that clarify?

Comment: I don't think you want to bother with the constructor -- reflect over the private fields instead. `moAppName`, for example, contains an instance of `EPayParamNode` that got passed `"APN"` in its creation. See if you can get at that value from the `EPayParamNode` instance.

Comment: The EPayParamNode instance doesn't return anything useful to get to the "APN". It only returns its own properties.